# Vue in Django app - How to setup Vue instance from static js files

Tags: django, vue.js

I'm struggling with initializing the vue instance from separate js file (I don't ant to keep the code inside each template html).

template:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cinema project</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initail-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    {% load static %}
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="list-group mt-2">
            {% for x in huj%}
                <li class="list-group-item">{{x}}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        [[rate]]
    </div>
    <script src="{% static 'js/vue.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js_file:

```
new Vue({
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    el:".container",
    data: { 
        rate: "test",
    },
  })
```

The staticfiles_dir works - I tested it with some random js code. In the above vue instance simply can't hook with my template. Is there any way to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue requires each component to have ONE single root node. Your code example has two because you've placed [[rate]] outside the ul.

Maybe this works better:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <ul class="list-group mt-2">
                {% for x in huj%}
                    <li class="list-group-item">{{x}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
           [[rate]]
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Still the same :/

Comment: I agree it should work, as demonstrated in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eh7xgk20/, so if its not your setup, then it should be something else. Have you verified that your js/vue.js is loaded (maybe drop in an alert to see that the file is loaded), are there any errors in developer console (F12)?

Comment: If I put vue instance straight below the template body then it works but as I said I need to import it from separate file. I guess there must be something else to do, not only raw definition of vue instance as presented in my code.

Comment: oh.. maybe load Vue first and then load your own js/vue.js ;-)

Comment: I did try it with - Imported vue in js file. Same result :(

Comment: No, i literally mean: First:    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script> Then: 
    <script src="{% static 'js/vue.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>